# Getting Modified Time as different credentials in Python

Tags: python, file, authentication, python-datetime

I try to get a file modified time from another server with different credentials. Here are my codes I can get modified time but need to do that with different user. Print "alert" If the time between the modified date and the current time is more than 5 minutes.

```
import os
import time
from datetime import date



try:
    modify = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(r'\\Server1\Users.txt'))
    print(modify)
    today = date.today()

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("no file")
```

Comment: Do you have problems with the authentification or the time part?

Comment: Actually both, I dont know how I check modify time with different authentication and How I calculate whether the time difference between the modify time and the current time is 5 minutes.